# Recording in MI phones getting voice low of other side

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, mediarecorder, android-audiomanager

I have a recording app which records voice on call, app works fine upto nougat but getting problem in android 8.0 specially with MI phones.
What should i have to change?

I am using mediarecorder and VOICE_COMMUNICATION as audio source.

```
 stopRecording();
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());


    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    recordstarted = true;
```

Recording file is ok but voice of other side is quite low. 
Any help will be much appreciated. THANK YOU

Comment: If it's specific to one manufacturer there's not much you can do..

Comment: but its a requirement and its mandatory